# Zabbix DB connection support DNS SRV Records

Tags: mysql, cluster, zabbix, mysql-cluster, srv-record

I have Zabbix Mysql 3 node Innodb cluster, which gives 3 DNS SRV Records with Mysql Router endpoints. I need to configure Zabbix server and web DB connection as DB host (e.g _mysql._tcp.example.com), but it doesn't work.

Are the any configuration parameter Zabbix offer that will allow to enter DNS SRV records? OR Is there an alternative available.

Comment: Do you want to monitor this MySQL or to store Zabbix's own database in it? In latter case, according to the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/installation/frontend#configure-db-connection), you have to specify the exact connection connection information, it doesn't support quering DNS SRV. However, if you want just to discover databases to monitor, you may write your own template with the discovery through DNS SRV.

Comment: Thanks Nikita, yes, I want to store Zabbix own database into 3 Node Mysql Cluster. As DNS SRV query not supported by default, I was thinking to use HAproxy that resolve DNS SRV records and allow failover configuration to cover Mysql Resiliency.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Zabbix's database connector does not use DNS SRV records to locate the database. According to [the manual](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/installation/frontend#configure-db-connection), you need to provide the exact connection details.

Using haproxy to make database reliable should be possible.

As I see you are trying to build highly available solution here, make sure you've read the [Zabbix's own documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/concepts/server/ha) regarding that. Also "MySQL cluster" might mean different things; if you meant Galera cluster then I'm afraid that wouldn't be the best possible solution. The Zabbix database usage pattern is to write many small records into few tables (one table per handled data type), which might be not the best usage pattern for the Galera. The standard primary-standby (or "master-slave") database replication is the best match to the Zabbix's built-in HA capability.